# Sky coverage plot using Python/Astropy

Tags: observational-astronomy, coordinate, software

I want to recreate a plot where the area that is not visible from a certain point on earth (latitude and longitude) trough a full year. An example of this plots for example can be:

[image]

Where in white is marked the zone a telescope is not seeing over all year. I searched in internet but i can not find anything related on how to do it, also [Astropy](https://www.astropy.org/) don't seem to have any tool to do this calculus.

My first idea for the approach can be first of all maybe represent in equatorial coordinates where this areas should be straight lines (but i don't know how to calculate the coordinates that this straight lines will have). And maybe after we can transform to galactic coordinates somehow.

If someone have an idea on how to do this will be helpful.

Comment: Not a lot of math involved, it's simply any object with a declination less than (in the northern hemisphere) -(90-lattitude).

Comment: [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) will be extremely useful for this, you can include all kinds of extra goodies quite easily. For example obscuration by twilight as done using Skyfield in [Satellite Constellation Avoidance with the Rubin Observatory Legacy Survey of Space and Time](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.15908)